# Start Camera using Xamarin

Tags: xamarin, camera, xamarin.forms

I am new in Mobile Development. I am trying create a cross platform app using Xamarin Forms. So far I am doing good, but I am having a problem trying to get a way to start a Camera. I understand a Camera is a Native function. Can someone please give me a step by step example on how to do this. Treat me like an idiot. The examples I came across are very vague and some don't even have finished code. if you have a link/s that you believe might help. I'm really struggling with this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Media Plugin](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin).

> Media Plugin for Xamarin and Windows is a Simple cross platform plugin
>   to take photos and video or pick them from a gallery from shared code.

You can add it via Nuget to the solution from [here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugin.Media).

```
takePhoto.Clicked += async (sender, args) =>
{
    await CrossMedia.Current.Initialize();

    if (!CrossMedia.Current.IsCameraAvailable || !CrossMedia.Current.IsTakePhotoSupported)
    {
        DisplayAlert("No Camera", ":( No camera available.", "OK");
        return;
    }

    var file = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new Plugin.Media.Abstractions.StoreCameraMediaOptions
    {
        Directory = "Sample",
        Name = "test.jpg"
    });

    if (file == null)
        return;

    await DisplayAlert("File Location", file.Path, "OK");

    image.Source = ImageSource.FromStream(() =>
    {
        var stream = file.GetStream();
        file.Dispose();
        return stream;
    }); 
};
```

You can read more about it's usage [here](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/MediaPlugin#usage).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the XLabs project for Xamarin Forms:

https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs

This is a short installation guide for registering the services XLabs offers, including the camera:
http://www.matrixguide.ch/Datenablage/diverses/How_to_Install_and_Setup_XLabs.pdf

Here is the XLabs camera api:
https://github.com/XLabs/Xamarin-Forms-Labs/wiki/Camera

And here is a short code example:
https://bizmonger.wordpress.com/2015/10/19/xamarin-forms-camera-integration/

The advantage of using XLabs is that it allows you to handle other native components as well like the GPS, Accelerometer etc.